# I'm not able to delete records from wp_options wordpress Via SQL

Tags: wordpress

I'm having some issues to remove records that have been stored on wp_options wordpress through my plugin. I'm trying to remove the data when the plugin is uninstalled, but it doesn't work ....I'm getting this message from wordpress --> Deletion failed: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress. Can someone help me please?

```
global $wpbd;
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM  wp_options WHERE option_name = 'headerscripts' AND option_name ='footerscripts '");
```

Comment: Your SQL query won't match any records, because you're using `AND` for your check, and the `option_name` can't match both of those values. You might want to write, `WHERE option_name = 'headerscripts' OR option_name ='footerscripts'`. You should also remove that trailing space in `'footerscripts '` because that won't match the records either.

Comment: I tried in that way ---> WHERE option_name = 'headerscripts' OR option_name ='footerscripts'   but it doesn't work either ....that's weird.